# WCF Simplified configuration 4.5 new feature?

Tags: wcf

I was going through new WCF 4.5 features http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456789.aspx and was trying out Simplified Generated Configuration Files. When i generate the config files in 4.0 and 4.5 both of them are same. They do not have default values.

Am i missing something here ?

Comment: According to the link, the values are emitted in the configuration file only if they aren't equal to the default value.  Can you post an example of the 4.0 and 4.5 files that you think don't show this in action?

Comment: You can edit your question and post the code there.

Comment: I just created a default WCF project one in 4.0 and then 4.5 and said add reference in a console application. I always ended as below. Not able to post the complete code because of char restriction. 
        
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:36275/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />

Comment: Tired...The complete code does not go. But thats what i see irrespective its 4.0 and 4.5.

Comment: You need to be clear: **4.0** gave you simplified configuration on the **server-side**, while **4.5** gave you simplified configuration on the **client-side** (when doing an `Add Service Reference`)

Comment: @marc_s - That's the part I was missing when I read OP's link.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @marc_s i was trying the client side only , add service reference.Do not find any difference.

Comment: And you're **100% sure** that you're using .NET **4.5** (and not 4.0) ??

Comment: @marc_s yes. I created new project with proper target framework.

Comment: @ShivprasadKoirala, This simplification of config feature is on client side when the add service reference generates a config. Question to you - Are you trying the 4.0 targeted project on a machine with 4.5 runtime installed? If so you may see a simplified config being generated even if you target 4.0, because of the fact 4.5 is an in-place upgrade of 4.0. Some of your 4.0 behaviors may be overridden by the 4.5 bits. Try generating service reference on a machine with just 4.0 & another on a machine with 4.5 to compare.

Comment: @Praburaj I do not have a clean machine i am using visual studio 2012  and creating both client and WCF project using the target framework drop down. The Config file is generated by VS add service reference and i expected it to behave differently as the per the framework selected.
Let me see if i can a get target machine which just has 4.0. But i think this is more of feature in 4.0 and not of 4.5 as answered by tim below.

Yes i am seeing the client config file only.

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't find anything *specifically* on 4.0 vs 4.5, the link you referenced shows a config file first for 3.0 and then one for 4.5.

Beginning with 4.0, simplified config files were introduced that had the concepts of default bindings and default endpoints - meaning that you could create an out-of-the-box WCF service application in 4.0 or 4.5 and there would be no binding or endpoint defined - you can verify this by looking at the web.config files for your 4.0 and 4.5 service.

When you add a service reference, you most likely used an "http://" URI - by default, "http" maps to `basicHttpBinding`. So let's look at the snippet you posted in the comments:

```
 <endpoint address="localhost:36275/Service1.svc"
           binding="basicHttpBinding" 
           bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
           contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" 
           name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
```

Everything the client needs to communicate with the service is there - the address, the binding to use, the binding configuration to use and the contract.

If you look in the client config file, you should see the following as well:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Which corresponds to the binding specified by the endpoint's `bindingConfiguration` attribute.  Since the defaults are being used, the other properties for the binding are not specified.

In 3.0 and 3.5, the binding section would have had all the properties of the binding specified with default values - in 4.0 and later it does not.

You're not missing anything - other than the documentation being a little misleading in that it implies this is a 4.5 feature, when it reality it's a 4.0 and 4.5 feature.

Comment: Thanks @tim  i think it was a 4.0 feature and its just been stressed ( or probably marketed) in 4.5.